# compare differences between conditions with emmeans

Tags: r, mixed-model, lsmeans

With the following model

```
subject <- factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),each=4, times=2))
dep <- c(5,4,9,3,4,4,2,1,10,7,8,7,1,2,1,1,5,10,1,7,3,2,1,4,3,8,7,3,1,1,2,1,15,10,20,11,2,2,1,3,11,12,9,7,2,3,1,2,11,9,8,9,3,4,2,1) 

f1 <- factor(rep(c(rep("Female",times=16),rep("Male",times=12)), times=2))
f2 <- factor(rep(c("day1","day2","day3","day4"),times=14))

data <- data.frame(sub=subject, dep=dep, f1=f1, f2=f2)

m <- lmer(dep ~ f1*f2 + (1|sub), data=data)
```

I calculated contrasts with `emmeans`

```
pairs(emmeans(m, ~f2|f1))
```

Now I'd like to be able to compare females and males for contrast `day1 - day2`. Basically compare

```
f1 = Female:
 contrast      estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 day1 - day2  0.8750000 2.135136 43   0.410  0.9765
```

with

```
f1 = Male:
 contrast      estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 day1 - day2 -1.5000000 2.465443 43  -0.608  0.9289
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just read this right off the summary of fixed effects?  It should be on the line `f1Male:f2day2` in the output of `summary(m)`.

Comment: Thanks @whuber, that's right, I keep forgetting the `summary` function. I suppose I haven't quite understood how to read the output from `summary` adequately. My impression is that with rvl's answer you can easily test any simple effect you like, but not so with the `summary(m)`. For example `summary(m)` does not provide the estimate of contrast `day2-day3` for females vs males (which is given automatically with rvl's code), which suggests that additional manual calculations need to be performed

Comment: You can often recode the dummy variables so that the summary displays exactly the tests you want.  Because that's not terribly flexible, most statistical software offers a post-hoc procedure to test any linear contrast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
contrast(emmeans(m, ~f1*f2), interaction = “consec”)
```

But @whuber’s comment does apply in a case as simple as this one.

Or you may prefer

```
pairs(pairs(emmeans(m, ~ f2|f1)), by = NULL)
```

That is, compute the results you already have, remove the `by` grouping, and compare the two pairwise differences.

Comment: That's great @rvl, many thanks! The last code gives me an error though `Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘structure("lmerModLmerTest", package = "lmerTest")’ to a data.frame`

Comment: Oops, left out the emmeans call. I fixed it

Comment: your code works great if I want to test every single pairwise difference. However, what if I'm interested in only two of the contrasts, say
`day1 - day2,Female - day1 - day2,Male` and `day1 - day3,Female - day1 - day3,Male` while adjusting just for these two contrasts?

Comment: Use something like `contrast(pairs(...), "trt.vs.ctrl1", exclude = 4, by = NULL)`. See `help("contrast")` and `help("contrast-methods")`

Comment: Oops, I think I have it backwards (may I encourage you to use *meaningful* factor names?). Use something like `emm <- emmeans(m, ~f2|f1);` `pairs(contrast(emm, "ctrl.vs.trt1", exclude = "day4"), by = NULL)`

Comment: Thanks @rvl! I think you meant `pairs(contrast(emm, "trt.vs.ctrl", exclude = "day4"), by = NULL)`, right?
However, this is still showing me non insteresting comparisons like `day2-day1,Female - day3-day1,Male`
These are the comparisons I'm trying to correct:
`day1-day2,Female - day1-day2,Male`
`day1-day3,Female - day1-day3,Male`
`day2-day3,Female - day2-day3,Male`

Comment: If I do `pairs(emm,exclude="day4")`, then I just need a way to compare the `Female` row with the corresponding `Male` row to get the comparisons above. I tried all sorts of combinations using `pairs` and `contrast` as well as different methods (as specified in contrasts-methods) but cannot figure out a way of doing this

Comment: Just look at the documentation for `contrast`. For example, you can just specify a list of the contrast coefficients you want, rather than specifying a named contrast method.